# Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies. To update the CocoaPods specs, run: pod repo update

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

**When I start to run flutter ios the project with "flutter run" it gives**
`Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
pod repo update

Error running pod install
`

**Then I run "pod install" inside ios/  It gives**

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
In Podfile:
firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 1.12.0, which depends on
Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.11.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.11.0)`.

You have either:

- out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.

**Then
I tried pod install --repo-update
It gives**

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
In Podfile:
firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 1.12.0, which depends on
Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.11.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.11.0)`.

You have either:

- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

**Do you want to help me about this problem?**

Comment: Can you share your Podfile?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/t/s!Aljz9e21ww1GiTA_dINqcmbVM-Vb?e=KoLIHI  it is here

Comment: can you share your yaml file, your pod file create with your yaml file.

Answer (score 8):

You should go to iOS folder and delete:

pods folder and podfile.lock

[image]

after that, you should add below lines to yaml file

```
  firebase_core: ^1.12.0         "[last version in dev dart]"
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.4     "[last version in dev dart]"
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.3.0.  "[last version in dev dart]"
  firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0.   "[last version in dev dart]"
```

run your app to install and update pod file

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did this but finally I fixed this problem by using "pod repo remove trunk" and "pod install."

Answer (score 3):

This is solved by deleting

Podfile.lock
pods folder

updating these packages

firebase_core: ^1.12.0
firebase_analytics: ^8.3.4
firebase_crashlytics: ^2.3.0.
firebase_messaging: ^11.1.0.

then running first

pod repo remove trunk

and finally

pod install

Comment: pod repo remove trunk